# Best practices for putting values inside sql enums

Tags: php, mysql, sql, enums

I have two enum columns in my mysql table:

```
gender enum('male', 'female') not null,
user_type enum('hr', 'manager', 'qa') not null
```

One of my coworkers insisted that it is not a good idea to use lower case in all enum values because it will not look good in pages. For example,

// profile.php
User Type: HR(stands for human resources)
    Gender: male

should be:

// profile.php
User Type: HR
Gender: Male

My primary reason for ignoring cases is I will be comparing values on these columns lots of times. For example:

```
if (user_type == "hr")
```

it would be very annoying if I have errors just for case mismatch. And what about the gender column? Is it really fine to upper case it?

I suppose the UI side could just capitalize it like:

```
<?php echo strtoupper($userType) ?>
```

I don't have much knolege in sql so I'd like to ask: Is there best practices regarding case conventions on enum values? Note I'm not talking about naming enum columns.

Comment: Well, you could use a case insensitive collation (most 'default' collations are) - but either way, it's pretty easy to control this kind of thing in your css

Comment: Use what ever is practical for your purpose. Having a strict adherence to casing is a bit of a problem. For example, on forms it may look good for having the proper case but in reports i.e. there are 5 male and 5 female surpervisors, would look strange if proper casing was used.

Comment: This question is either opinion based or too broad (or both). You can even argue if it's a good idea to use ENUM in MySQL at all. However I think you need to decide if it is data or internal keys to use in your code. Tomorrow they want you to change "HR" to "employee" and your code (`user_type == "HR"`) won't work any more, just because the data changed. It would be better to have some kind of mapping - Either in the DB (`gender_key, gender_label`) or in your application (`$labels['male'] = 'Male'` and `echo $labels[$genderKey]`). To support multiple languages, you have to do it either way.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about Best Practices, then ***YES***. You should use `ENUM` values in upper case. Because, they are constants.

And, AFAIK, in all programming languages constants declared as *UPPERCASE*.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, in all the languages that I used which have the concept of enums, both in the documentation and in the enums defined in the libraries provided by the language the enums are not written in uppercase or lowercase, but instead they use some variation of camel case, like `Small, Medium, Big` or `szSmall, szMedium, szBig`. Some examples:

- [C# enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum)
- [C++ enums](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e.aspx)
- [Delphi enums](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Enumerated_Types)

Of course in all of these examples the enums values are not strings and they have a name and a value so you don't have a problem with comparisons nor with the output (because you would output its *value*, not its *name*).

Since in MySQL the value is also the name if you are using the values of the enum for any output you should use the case that have more sense in that output (the same that you would use if the column were a regular `CHAR` column), for example `'HR','Management','QA'`. As noted in the comments the default collations should be already case insensitive so you don't have a problem in comparisons or joins.

In PHP you can use [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) or if you don't like it for any reason  [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)/[`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php):

```
if (strcasecmp(user_type,"hr")==0) // best options IMO
if (strcasecmp(user_type,"HR")==0) // best options IMO
if (strtolower(user_type)=="hr")
if (strtoupper(user_type)=="HR")
```

That is not that I'm against of using always a consistent case, in fact, I always use it and I worked a lot of time with case insensitive languages where it's not needed. But the priority is that the program provide the desired results, because you are writing code not (only) for fun but to achieve something, if the proper way of naming departments is `'HR','Management','QA'` you can't use `'hr','management','qa'` because it looks prettier in your code.

That's said, if the enums are used only internally, for example because you use them only as id's and the descriptions are stored in a `Descriptions` table, then use the case that is best suited for you and your coworkers.